# why does this always give heads, and can i make the timer invisible?

Tags: batch-file, math

can someone explain why this happens, and/or give an example on it, or help me with hiding the timer?

```
@echo off

:main
    setlocal
    set /p range=What number range should it be from 1-(number)?  :
    set /a coinFlip=%random% %%%range% +1
    if %coinFlip% gtr ((%range%/2)-(%range%%2)) (
      title Its Heads!
      echo It flipped Heads!
      goto exit
   ) else (
      title Its Tails!
      echo It flipped Tails!
      goto exit
   )
    endlocal
:exit
    timeout /t 3 /nobreak
    cls
    title BatchCookin Executer
    exit /b 0
```

i tried running it, expecting either an error or it working the intended way, but it just kept giving heads.

Comment: `%range%/2-` and `%range%%2` won't work. The only command that is able to do math in `cmd` is `set /a`. See `set /?` for details. You need to calculate *before*  comparing with `if`

Comment: I am a little confused why you would need a range to do a coin flip, which has exactly a 50/50 chance each time of being heads or tails. Therefore, this should do exactly that `set /a rnd=%random% %% 2 | find "0">nul && echo Heads || echo Tails`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch doesn't let you do in-line math, so you have to calculate the range difference separately and then use that in your `if` statement. Also, you can silence any command by adding `>nul` to the end of it.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:main
set /p range=What number range should it be from 1-(number)?  :
set /a coinFlip=%random% %% %range% +1
set /a range_diff=(%range%/2)-(%range%%%2)

if %coinFlip% gtr %range_diff% (
    title Its Heads!
    echo It flipped Heads!
    goto exit
) else (
    title Its Tails!
    echo It flipped Tails!
    goto exit
)
    
:exit
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
cls
title BatchCookin Executer
exit /b 0
```

---

It's worth noting that usually when you do a coin flip, you just need to do `%RANDOM% %% 2`:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /a flip=%RANDOM% %% 2

if "%flip%"=="0" (
    echo It's heads!
) else (
    echo It's tails!
)
```